# Setting different `footer version` from admin panel/table Magento 2

Tags: magento2, footer, footer-links

By default, I have footer version as `footer_1`.
On looking upon the code `footer.phtml` , there are multiple footer version
`footer_2`, `footer_3`, `footer_4`
How can I enable each footer from my `Admin panel` and from which table also.

```
<?php // Get footer version ?>
<?php $themeHelper = $this->helper('MGS\Mpanel\Helper\Data') ?>
<?php $footer = $themeHelper->getStoreConfig('mgstheme/footer/footer');?>
```

and condition for footer version check goes on

```
 <?php if($footer == 'footer_1'): ?> // footer version check
```

I don't understand, from where did the `$themeHelper` is getting the footer versions, and how can I change with other footer versions like `footer_2`, `footer_3` etc.
If it has both approaches from admin panel and from database table too(so that I can use MySQL query to update) kindly enlighten me.
I am new to Magento

[image]

Comment: It looks like a ready-made theme. Better you refer their docs for this and don't change directly in the third party themes which makes upgrade difficult.

Answer (score 0):

As per your code you are using a ready made theme, which has many footer styles.

if you look at:

```
<?php $themeHelper = $this->helper('MGS\Mpanel\Helper\Data') ?>
```

above code will instantiate helper in your `phtml`.
Once we get helper, we can access its function like:

```
<?php $footer = $themeHelper->getStoreConfig('mgstheme/footer/footer');?>
```

If you look into `Data.php` in helper folder of module, there will be a function `getStoreConfig`.

This function getting store configuration value based on parameter passed.

If you go to `System->Configuration`, there will be some theme related settings.

In your function `mgstheme/footer/footer`

```
mgstheme - Section name
footer - Group Name
footer - field name
```

So there is a dropdown in admin, where you can choose different footer.

```
Footer1 - footer_1
Footer2 - footer_2
Footer3 - footer_3

----
```

based on value of `$footer`, it is rendering footer design in your phtml.

Hope above will help!

Comment: first, Configuration is in`Stores->Configuration` not System->Configuration
see my updated question , there is nothing in footer dropdown

Comment: Strange, you only notice  System->Configuration in whole answer! Great!